# Should parameter and argument related tags be deprecated?

Tags: discussion, tags

Active community member @amalloy has stated that he or she "wouldn't be surprised to find that there are no appropriate uses of any of those tags." The tags in question are:

- [arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arguments)
- [parameter-passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameter-passing)
- [optional-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-parameters), and
- [keyword-argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyword-argument)

This is very surprising to a newcomer who could likely make the mistake of thinking those tags should be used. As a new contributor, I made the same mistake myself with [my recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430354/clojure-keyword-argument-default-depending-on-other-keyword-argument).

Shouldn't we edit the description of these tags with a similar warning to [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data)? Its description says:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG! This tag is hopelessly broad and doesn't really tell us what the question is about.

I think we should do this so that useless tags are not used, requiring others to edit the question, since the tags used aren't being followed.

Comment: Just because people cannot use a tag properly does not mean the tag needs to go.  If people are using them incorrectly already that means they have not read them so putting *DO NOT USE THIS TAG* is not really going to help.  We really need a overhaul on how tags get added to questions to make sure the right tags are added.