# Shall we synonymize [optional-arguments] and [optional-parameters]?

Tags: discussion, support, synonym-request

Let's synonymize [optional-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-arguments) (x 220) to [optional-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-parameters) (x 1073)!

They are used the same (and should be).

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274793/should-parameter-and-argument-related-tags-be-deprecated and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361273/should-optional-parameters-be-the-default