# Should [optional-parameters] be the default?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I recently noticed [optional-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-parameters), [optional-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-arguments), [default-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default-parameters), and [default-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default-arguments) all seem to refer to the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700530/golang-variadic-constructor-function-create-a-person-contact-in-golang) [scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359613/strange-behavior-with-function-overriding-and-optional-params-in-groovy): an optional parameter which has a default argument.

Making all the tags synonyms is a good way to reflect this. I've chosen [optional-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-parameters) as the "base" for the rest as it has the most tagged questions, and you can [vote on the synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/optional-parameters/synonyms) if you have at least a score of 5 in [optional-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-parameters).

If not enough people vote there, then hopefully a moderator can push the change through instead.

#### Why not just edit the wikis?

The tags getting used for the same situation could be solved by editing the tag wikis to more clearly differentiate them, but I believe there really is no such differentiation to be made.

To understand this, first let's look at the difference between [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameters) and [arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arguments). According to the [arguments wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/arguments/info):

> Usually "argument"... is the *value* of the parameter used within the called routine.

I'm not sure this distinction is that useful for most questions, but there is a difference, and the tags do seem to be used somewhat differently.

Let's look at what each of the offending tags mean and how they are used:

1. [optional-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-parameters)

   Parameters for which arguments are optional.
2. [optional-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-arguments)

   Optional arguments can't, by definition, exist without optional parameters. The difference between the two is also quite blurry. Is a call with two arguments instead of the usual three utilizing an optional parameter or an optional argument?
3. [default-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default-parameters)

   If we follow the definition above, default parameters are parameters that a function has by default, such as `this` for methods in Java (as opposed to say, Python, where `self` is explicit). They are **not** a default value for a parameter, this would be a default *argument*. But even [the wiki messes this up](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/default-parameters/info), and thus the tag is used exclusively as a synonym of default arguments.
4. [default-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default-arguments)

   As mentioned above, this is a default value for a parameter. While it might be possible to have a default argument for a mandatory parameter, it would make little sense. And every optional parameter must have some value that is assumed when it is absent, e.g. a default argument.

#### Alternatives

If the community feels these tags are distinct enough to keep separate, then the tag wikis need to be heavily edited and clarified, as in their current states, it is hard to tell when to use one tag over another.

Comment: Perhaps it isn't helpful to note, but in Fortran parameters cannot be optional but arguments may be.  In this language, though, parameters and arguments are completely different concepts (only the latter relating to procedures, except for parameterized function results).

Comment: @francescalus interesting... That sort of seems like a whole other issue as [tag:parameters] seems like it is being used for Fortran "arguments" in many questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran+parameters

However, if you think two tags above should be kept separate, please post an answer explaining why.

Comment: That's a very minor cleaning up I can do when I have a computer to hand.  Those uses of [tag:parameter] seem mostly unhelpful.  Parameters in Fortran are those things which describe data objects, but "parameter" is also colloquially used to mean a named constant (because they have the `parameter` attribute).  A first glance few of those questions relate truly to what the tag intends.

Comment: Arguments and parameters refer to different things, you say this yourself. I don't follow the rest of your logic because it all seems to forget that first concept.

Comment: @TinyGiant If the difference is so clear to you, I'd be happy to hear the difference between optional parameters and optional arguments and cases where you'd use one tag but the other would be inappropriate. In fact, such an explanation would be incredibly useful to include in the respective tag wikis.

Comment: Take the following parameter list: `(a, b, ...cde)`. This function would receive a few _default_ parameters and an unlimited number of _optional_ parameters. Thus the difference between default and optional parameters has been demonstrated. Then whether or not the question concerns the arguments or the parameters themselves would determine the proper tagging. Ultimately it would depend on the language being used how the questions using it will be tagged, _and that is not a bad thing_. This seems at most like a useless conflation of multiple concepts.

Comment: @TinyGiant Why do we need default and optional parameter tags then? It seems default parameters can just be called "parameters" unless there is a need to distinguish them from optional parameters, in which case why not just use the optional parameter tag. Basically I see no case where you would use the default parameters tag without optional parameters being involved.

Comment: Why do we need to not have them? Why must we all commence busy work imposing unnecessary limitations upon ourselves? What problem has this caused? What harm does it do? And what good exactly will this accomplish?

Comment: @TinyGiant you could ask that about any tag synonym request. Why should we make synonyms at all? It's so people can find questions related to their interests/needs without having to specify 10 tags to get all the questions about a single topic.

Comment: @TinyGiant Also I feel like you're now a far cry from your original "parameters and arguments are different, so let's leave these tags separate" position. It's hard to argue against someone who doesn't stand still.

Comment: No, we do these things when a problem has been identified. When a tag or set of tags is actively causing confusion or harm, then we act. We don't all just hop-to because you feel like a few topics are a little too similar. My original argument and every argument thereafter stand. The fact that you fail to see the connection is not my fault.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162294/discussion-between-river-and-tiny-giant).