# Synonymize [default-parameters] and [default-arguments]

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request

[default-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default-parameters) excerpt:

> A default parameter is a function or method parameter that has a default value provided to it. If the user does not supply a value for this parameter, the default value will be used. If the user does supply a value for the default parameter, the user supplied value is used.

[default-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default-arguments) excerpt:

> A default argument is a value passed to a certain parameter of a function if the user does not explicitly supply a value for that parameter.

Both of these refer to the same concept of being able to define default values for function arguments that are used if the user does not supply them.

These tags should be merged.

Comment: @RyanM I am not sure why you replaced the [tag:feature-request] with [tag:support].

Comment: Sounds right to me; I'll do this in a week or so if no one objects.  Also, input is welcome on which should be the canonical tag... normally I would pick the larger one, but they differ in size by exactly one question...

Comment: *"I am not sure why you replaced the feature-request with support."* See the first bullet point at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonym-request/info.  Creating synonyms technically does not require moderator assistance, but in practice it does, because the user-level synonym-creation system is ... hard to use.

Comment: @RyanM Unless I happen to have enough upvoted answers in that tag. Which I usually don't.

Comment: Related: [Should \[optional-parameters\] be the default?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361273/15497888)

Comment: Neither of these is really an accurate term. I would say it should be called `default-parameter-values`.