# Too many [arguments]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

Today I encountered this question with whopping 3 tags that seemingly mean the same: [How to pass optional parameters to a Perl subroutine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456142/how-to-pass-optional-parameters-to-a-perl-subroutine)

They are: [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameters) [arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arguments) and [parameter-passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameter-passing). We also have [optional-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-arguments) that is not present in this question to complement [optional-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-parameters) that does.

In my opinion, [parameter-passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameter-passing) is completely useless and should be aliased to tag that survives next merge. [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameters) and [arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arguments) are synonyms of each other, that should be merged/aliased. Same for [optional-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-arguments) and [optional-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-parameters).

Which direction to merge is up for discussion, but for the reference, [argument-passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argument-passing) already leads to [parameter-passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameter-passing).

Comment: Why merge or burninate and not synonymize all those to the most used one?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274793/should-parameter-and-argument-related-tags-be-deprecated

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277541/shall-we-synonymize-optional-arguments-and-optional-parameters

Comment: Am I right that you're only requesting a [tag:synonym-request] but not actual burnination?

Comment: @Kyll, why not both? Also I'd prefer same single word in all related tags, not "most used one" in each pair.

Comment: @rene, I disagree with 274793 - there are uses for those tags when discussing things related to parameters (named, optional, validation, function signatures, etc), it is just there's no need for specific tag for every little nuance.

Comment: There is at least one place where parameter is used but it is definitely not called an argument and that is in the context with  DbCommands, at least in [tag:c#] (or .Net to be precise) . Not sure if that holds for other contexts and I'm not sure if I care enough to lose that distinction.

Comment: @rene, are you talking about [tag:sqlbindparameter]?

Comment: I'm having troubles coming up with a question where any of these tags can be the only valid tag.

Comment: "Klingon function calls do not have 'parameters' - they have 'arguments' - and they ALWAYS WIN THEM." ([Top 12 things likely to be overheard if you had a Klingon Programmer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/129751/31260))

Answer (score 1):

Many languages makes a distinct difference between the terms parameters and arguments. For example the C and C++ programming languages, see for example C17 chapter 3:

> 3.3 argument
>
> expression in the comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses in a
> function call expression, or a sequence of preprocessing tokens in the
> comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses in a function-like
> macro invocation
>
> ...
>
> 3.16 parameter
>
> object declared as part of a function declaration or definition that
> acquires a value on entry to the function, or an identifier from the
> comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses immediately following
> the macro name in a function-like macro definition

In plain English, the items on the caller side are arguments and the items on the function side are parameters. Example:

```
void func (int a, int b, int c); // parameters

void caller (void)
{
  func(a, b, c); // arguments
}
```

Comment: So if they're synonymous, then we can also synonymize *client* with *server* and *socket* with *plug* ...

Comment: How does [tag:parameter-passing] fits into this explanation? And honest question: even if some standards do distinguish them, can you imagine an actual question where this distinction is helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the [IEEE](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5733835) definitions.

**`argument`**

1. an independent variable.
2. a specific value of an independent variable.
3. a constant, variable, or expression used in a call to a software module to specify data or program elements to be passed to that module

**`parameter`**

1. a variable that is given a constant value for a specified application.
2. a constant, variable, or expression that is used to pass values between software modules.
3. a symbol that can take a range of values defined by a set it is defined as a constant in the signature.

---

I once had a college course which taught that `parameter` is the compile-time definition while `argument` is the runtime value. In practice, I've seen no benefit from differentiating the two; and any discrepancy between their definitions appears pedantic.

Comment: *semantics* exist for a reason, and using *pedantic* as an argument ( *pun intended* ) is not constructive. There is a *semantic* of *constant* for *parameter* that is only mentioned once in the definition of *argument*. And some languages make a very *semantic* difference. Perl maybe not so much, but then Perl sucks mainly because it encourages everyone to make up their own semantics and idioms.

Comment: argument#3 and parameter#2 looks like words are just shuffled around.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, easy test question: can you provide a realistic question where it would be important to have [tag:parameter] instead of [tag:argument]?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - given the definitions above and the *constant semantic* of *parameter*, here is your question *"Does Erlang use arguments or parameters to functions?"*

Answer (score -7):

WOW! These are all the same. They all need to be alias or burninated. The tags are all too close. If you gave those tags to someone who never went to this site, and said "Describe the kind of questions you would find with this tag", you would get very similar answers. I think at the very least every thing should just point to [parameter]. If someone wanted to float the notion of eliminating them altogether, I could see that being a valid option as well.