# Shall we synonymize [named-parameters] and [keyword-argument]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

There are two tags, [named-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/named-parameters) and [keyword-argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyword-argument)

For me these are two synonyms. Should we make a synonym?

There seems to be differences between different programming languages. In Ruby the official documentation uses keyword-argument, but in discussions named parameters is also used. (Example: *[How can Ruby functions with named arguments get called with a hash instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56157747/how-can-ruby-functions-with-named-arguments-get-called-with-a-hash-instead)*)

If not, can we adapt the information of the two tags to clarify the difference.

Remarks:

- I just created information for [keyword-argument]
- See also *[Should parameter and argument related tags be deprecated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274793/should-parameter-and-argument-related-tags-be-deprecated)*

Comment: What would you suggest the target tag would be? (and why)

Comment: Not synonyms, "keyword argument" is specific to Python and Ruby.  While they cover the same concept, for example a C# or VB programmer would not have a shot at guessing what it could mean.  The primary language tag avoids them getting mixed up.

Comment: @JonClements To be honest, up to now I have no preference. I see the problem but I feel not competent to decide it. As a ruby developper I prefer the keyword argument, but I think I'm not objective for this :) . I want to wait if we get some more opinions. Maybe we have only to adapt the tag description. (Something like _similar concepts are called XXX in ...)

Answer (score 1):

Keyword Arguments appear to offer more functionality than a Named Parameter does. For example with Keyword Arguments you don't have to specify what the names are in the code however with a Named Parameter it would be expected to be predefined what the name is when writing the code.

Taken from the accepted answer on [Normal arguments vs. keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments)

> The other concept is on the function definition side: You can define a function that takes parameters by name -- and you don't even have to specify what those names are. These are pure keyword arguments, and can't be passed positionally. The syntax is
>
> ```
> def my_function(arg1, arg2, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> Any keyword arguments you pass into this function will be placed into a dictionary named kwargs. You can examine the keys of this dictionary at run-time, like this:
>
> ```
> def my_function(**kwargs):
>     print str(kwargs)
>
> my_function(a=12, b="abc")
>
> {'a': 12, 'b': 'abc'}
> ```